# Convert LINUX CURL command to Cloud PCF CLI command

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, command-line-interface, pcf

We are able to run the following Curl command from LINUX server putty:

```
curl —cert /path/to/file/XXXX.pem:<PWD> —key /path/to/file/XXXX.pem https://<URL>
```

However now we want to move all our applications to cloud servers and need to find a way to run above curl command from PCF Command Line Interface (CLI).

I did some research and found there is “cf curl” command, but cannot find a way to pass JKS or PEM file and it’s password.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

cf curl is intended to be used when writing CF CLI plugins and mainly to interact with the api directly. “cf curl” can execute a request to an API endpoint.
For ex:
cf curl /v2/apps -- retrieves the information about all of your apps

However It seems you are looking to call the apps deployed on cloud foundry using curl so you do't need cf curl rather need to make sure that you use the URL of the apps the running on PCF within your curl command. You should ideally be able to run from any server that has curl and doesn't have any Firewall rules to block such URLs..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no way we can pass JKS/PEM/CRT files directly from cf curl or cf api commands like we do in Linux curl command. I created a spring boot batch application in which I am passing certificate from rest template and then call my rest API. Now I can call this app using cf run-task command.